# Connecting two I2S data line from an audio codec using only one of the I2C's control clocks

Tags: stm32, i2s

I'm planning to receive audio data from an Audio codec (ak4619). I need to receive signals from 4 microphones and this device permit that through two left/right chanels.

In CubeIDE, I selected a MCU (STM32F446RET) and declared two I2S connections.

The Audio codec I2S IOs are like that:

[image: I2S codec connection]

I since there is 2 I2S data line but only one set of LRCLK, MCLK (clocked by a MCO on the MCU) and SD on the audio codec, can I use only one of the two I2S set of clocks and hope the synchronisation goes well?

Or should I use two separated devices with their own I2S set of signal and clock?

Thank you,

Comment: Have you figured it out?